# Hostname to IP Conflict in hadoop

Tags: networking, hadoop, network-programming, hadoop-yarn

I am running hadoop 2.2.0 . i installed it in linux 12.04. Sample wordcount, pi-estimator worked correctly. The problem is with **Web Interfaces**.

my /etc/hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       master
192.168.2.81    master
```

When i go with **"localhost"** it works fine as shown in fig[image: namenode log]

But when i change it to **"master"** it shows error as shown in following figure [image: namenode log with master]

HOw to solve this... and how come it is not determining IP address from hostname "master"?

Comment: why do you need to map master to 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts? Removing that line should fix your problem

Comment: actually it is by default present in /etc/hosts.  As I am using static ip, I added 192.168.2.81 to master

Answer (score 1):

Just have these 2.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.2.81    master
```

Then it should be fine.

Comment: I tried this... but still getting same error. 127.*.*.* is know as loopback address(* can have any value between 0-255). Is this thing have any connection with above concept

Comment: I've this configuration and it works like a charm. Try to give the IP instead of host-name. 
i.e. `http://192.168.2.81:50070`
It has to be the IP of your system.
To check the IP, execute this command.
`ifconfig`

Comment: If i go for IP instead of hostname-- it works. But I want it should work even with hostname.. do i need to update any file other than "/etc/hosts"

Comment: Nope. Just the /etc/hosts file. If it is configured here, then you should be able to ping . Try this.. `ping master` . If still it doesn't work, can you post your /etc/hosts file here?